# Run two make phony targets in parallel

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I (mis)use `make`'s phony targets for conveniently doing all sorts of random things in my project. For example:

```
.PHONY: css
css:
    @(sass foo.scss foo.css)
```

But sometimes these commands will run forever until I explicitly kill them. For instance when `sass` is watching a file for changes:

```
.PHONY: watch_css
watch_css:
    @(sass --watch foo.scss:foo.css)
```

This is fine, but sometimes I want to combine multiple recipes in a single target:

```
.PHONY: watch_css1
watch_css1:
    @(sass --watch foo1.scss:foo1.css)

.PHONY: watch_css2
watch_css2:
    @(sass --watch foo2.scss:foo2.css)

.PHONY: watch
watch: watch_css1 watch_css2
```

How can I get `make watch` to run both `watch_css1` and `watch_css2` in parallel? If I explicitly do `make -j2 watch` things work fine but is there a way to embed that into the makefile itself?

Comment: I'm assuming the target names `watch_css` appearing twice is a typo.  It's always better to create an actual running example that shows the problem you have and cut and paste it.

Comment: yes thanks for pointing that out. fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run make recursively:

```
watch:
        $(MAKE) -j2 watch_css1 watch_css2
```